# Get rows with cross value

Tags: sql

I am trying to select all those rows where t1.col1 value is in t1.col2 value AND t1.col2 value is in t1.col1 value. This imply that for a given row it exists the "mirror" value in another row.

For example, I would select both rows if:

```
col1   col2
A      B
B      A
```

But not select if the table contains only one of those 2 rows.

I tried the following query without success:

```
SELECT distinct t1.*
  FROM table AS t1
  INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t1.col1 = t2.col2 AND t2.col1 = t1.col2)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example where your query doesn't do what you want? I just tried it and it seems to be ok, but maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table to itself (using different aliases), for matching "opposing rows". For example:

```
select a.*
from t a
join t b on b.col2 = a.col1 and b.col1 = a.col2
```

Result:

```
col1  col2 
----- ---- 
A     B    
B     A
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i4BSfzVJtrSb6nnvGTGWL/0).

Comment: thanks. This looks like the code I wrote but, strange enough, I also got rows where the value in a column is not in any rows in the other column..

Comment: @delalma Your query is good. Can you reproduce the issue in a db-fiddle.com ?

Comment: thanks my error was from something different in the query. It worked.